# Error: UnregisteredEnv with OpenAI Universe on Python 3.5 Linux Mint. Cannot load any environments

Tags: openai-gym

I am running Python3.5 on Linux Mint.

I can import OpenAI Universe and Gym modules with no error, but when I try to run an example codes I get an error.

More specifically

> raise error.UnregisteredEnv('No registered env with id: {}'.format(id))
>   gym.error.UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: flashgames.DuskDrive-v0

I get similar errors for any environment.

I have installed Docker and retried it, but still doesn't work.
And I am having issues with Anaconda, will appreciate a non-Conda solution.

Thank you!

Code:

```
import gym
import universe 

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1)  # automatically creates a local docker container
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]  # your agent here
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

Comment: [2017-02-08 10:18:12,815] Making new env: flashgames.DuskDrive-v0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 116, in spec
    return self.env_specs[id]
KeyError: 'flashgames.DuskDrive-v0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scarlet/Projects/Python/Data Science/OpenAi.py", line 17, in <module>
    env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 140, in make
    return registry.make(id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 104, in make
    spec = self.spec(id)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 126, in spec
    raise error.UnregisteredEnv('No registered env with id: {}'.format(id))
gym.error.UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: flashgames.DuskDrive-v0